# Update query to change the value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column col_name whose datatype is tinyint and it can only store 0 or 1.Now i want to run an update query to change the col_name value from 0 to 1 if it contains 0 otherwise vise versa .Suggest different Ideas?
My current query not working but without any error is

```
UPDATE table SET col_name=case when col_name=0 then col_name=1 else col_name=0 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE the_table 
SET col_name = 1 - col_name
WHERE 1=1
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET col_name = 
    case when col_name = 0 
         then 1  
         else  0 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET col_name=case when col_name=0 then 1 else 0 end
```

You can also do

```
UPDATE table SET CASE col_name WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE
```

You just need to specify the numbers

[Case Statement Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)

Comment: is there no not operator in mysql

Comment: Give the second one a try, it's taken from the MySQL Reference

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
update updation
set digits = decode(digits, 1, 0, 0, 1, digits)
```

where updation is the name of the table and digits is the name of column